# How do you get the ticket created date in trac?

Tags: trac

I want to play with some really simple queries for a report, but I want to group everything by the creation date.  The problem I am having is that `time` exists in the database, but not the date.  From searching around in trac-related resources, it looks like I need to install trac.util.datefmt to be able to extract this information from datetime(time).  I can find the API documentation for trac.util.datefmt, but not a download link to get the .egg.

Am I going in the right direction?  If I can do what I need (i.e. get the creation month/day/year) without a plugin, what column do I use?  I don't see anything else in the schema that is reasonable.  If I do need trac.util.datefmt, where do I download it from?  And if I really need a different plugin, which one should I be using?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume Trac >= 1.0. The `time` column is unix epoch time: the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1st 1970. You can divide the value by 1e6 and put the value in a [converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to see an example of extracting the datetime from the `time` column. `trac.util.datefmt` is part of the egg that ships with Trac, but since you are working with reports it doesn't sound like you need to know more about that function to accomplish your aim.

In a Trac report the `time` column will be automatically formatted  [as a date](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracReports#Automaticallyformattedcolumns). You can look at the default report {1} as an example. I'm not sure how you intend to group by creation date. Do you wish to group tickets created in a certain datetime range?

Comment: thank you!  That gives me more information to work with.  I wouldn't mind learning how to group by date range, but at the moment I'm looking at grouping by a single day.

Comment: I should have noticed this behavior.  I always thought `as` in SQL was just an alias, but apparently trac does something special with it.  If I just use `time` I apparently get the epoch time.  If I use `time as created`, trac automatigally converts it into something human-understandable!

Comment: Ok, well `time as created` doesn't seem to help.  If I do a `select created from (select id, time as created from MyTable)`, I get what I expect, which is a list of all of the dates where a ticket was created.  However, if I use `select count(created) from (select id, time as created from MyTable)`, then I get a single number, rather than a table of each date with the number of tickets created on that date.  Do you have any suggestions?